Oracle SQL Cloud programmatically using Python 3.12
I'm experiencing difficulty connecting to Oracle SQL Cloud programmatically using Python 3.12. I'm running an M2 MacBook Pro within a virtualenv, and I've successfully installed the 'cx_Oracle' library. Despite trying various approaches, I haven't been able to resolve the issue. Has anyone encountered this problem and found a solution?

cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle
Client library: "dlopen(libclntsh.dylib, 0x0001): tried:
'libclntsh.dylib' (no such file),
'/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OSlibclntsh.dylib' (no such file),
'/usr/lib/libclntsh.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache),
'libclntsh.dylib' (no such file)". See
https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html
for help


Use python-oracledb (which is the successor to cx_Oracle) since it doesn't need Oracle Client libraries.  See the release announcement.

Did you read this?
